# How to get row with a specific value from a specific column in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I save data in a SQLite Database. The user can choose under which name his data will be saved. But how to get the row?

**I'm trying this:**

```
    public Cursor getRowByName(String rowName) {
    Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS,
            KEY_SAVENAME + "=?", new String[]{rowName}, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}
```

**But get the error:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: max (code 1): , while compiling: 
SELECT DISTINCT _id, saveName, date, time, month, erg, ergg, m, p, c, cg, x1, x2, 
x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, x10, x11, x12, x13, x14, x15, x16, y1, y2, y3, y4, 
y5, y6, y7, y8, y9, y10, y11, y12, y13, y14, y15, y16, c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, 
c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16, max, min, year FROM mainTable WHERE saveName=?
```

First it worked without the column `max` but afterwards I recognized that I need this and furthermore columns. But even if I had one more column (like `max`), I get this error.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Why all those nulls, you have only one parameter ?

Comment: Show the code that creates the `max` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the database structure, you **must** increase the **DATABASE_VERSION** constant value, in order for the `onUpgrade()` method to fire (it will delete and recreate the table/s).